# How to increase the font size of sidebar in Brackets code editor?

Tags: sidebar, adobe-brackets, code-editor

I am facing an issue in Brackets code editor. I am able to increase/decrease editor font size. But Sidebar font size is not changing anymore (screenshot attached). How can I fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Current brackets do not support changes in the font size for files in the file explorer menu.